# Volley sends empty POST request

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am trying to make a post request to a web server I made but Volley keeps on sending a empty request with no data resulting in a 500 error.

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val jsonParams: MutableMap<String?, String?> =
            HashMap()
        jsonParams["STATUS"] = "on"

        val myRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, "http://example.com/url_to_post_to/", JSONObject(
            jsonParams as Map<String, String>
        ), Response.Listener { response -> botStatus.text = response.toString() }, Response.ErrorListener { error -> print("There was a error!") }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                val headers =
                    HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                //headers["User-agent"] = "My useragent"
                return headers
            }
        }
        queue.add(myRequest)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the problem was. My server didn't accept JSON payload requests. I have switched to using the Fuel library now as well.